# Can we use BLS as a VRF?

Tags: signature, bls-signature, verifiable-random-function

Intuitively, it seems that the hash of a [BLS signature](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf) could be used as a [VRF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-vrf-05) as well. In a nutshell, `BLS-Signature` is the VRF output and the verification first checks the signature is valid, and then compute the hash over it to provide the VRF output. (Or similarly, one can provide `H(BLS-Signature)` as the VRF output and `BLS-Signature` as the VRF proof.)

1. Is this scheme a VRF ? Given a collision resistant hash function of course.
2. How would one would go about proving it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the random oracle model, the hash of a BLS signature makes a VRF essentially as secure as the BLS signature scheme (provided the verifier accepts only the unique canonical encoding of each signature).

This works because BLS signatures are unique.  Fix a pairing $e\colon G_1 \times G_2 \to G_T$ on groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of prime order.  For any fixed $A \in G_2$, the homomorphism $\phi_A\colon \sigma \to e(\sigma, A)$ is an injection (or the system is trivially insecure) because $G_1$ has prime order.  Let $B \in G_2$ be the standard base point.  A putative signature $\sigma \in G_1$ under public key $P \in G_2$ on a message $m$ satisfies the signature equation $$e(H(m),P) = e(\sigma,B) = \phi_B(\sigma).$$  Since $\phi_B$ is an injection, there is at most one possible signature $\sigma$ for any public key $P$ and any message $m$.

Comment: Does that fullfill the guarantees of a VRF though ? From the first VRF paper from Micali, uniqueness and pseudo randomness are not the same thing. BLS is a VUF but *not* a VRF. Furthermore, it does not seem to be resistant against malicious key generation attack (to fulfill pseudo randomness).

Comment: @Nikkolasg BLS brings unpredictability and uniqueness; the random oracle brings uniformity of the output.  No matter what public key you choose (as long as it is a valid public key in $G_2$), there is at most one signature $\sigma$ for each message $m$, and $H(\sigma)$ is an independent uniform random bit string for each $\sigma$.  (Maybe use $H(\text{‘message’} \mathbin\| m)$ and $H(\text{‘output’} \mathbin\| \sigma)$ if you're using the same hash function $H$ for the signature's message hash and the VRF's output hash.)

Comment: (It may also be prudent to hash the public key in too: $H(\text{‘message’} \mathbin\| P \mathbin\| m)$, $H(\text{‘output’} \mathbin\| P \mathbin\| \sigma)$.  This is a cheap measure that may be helpful to mitigate the impact of multi-target attacks and perhaps more exotic scenarios where the adversary knows a relation between two public keys but not what the two public keys are _a priori_.)

Comment: Imagine I would be using a signature scheme that produce a biased distribution of signature. If I hash the signature, the output will loose its algebraic structure but the distribution will still be biased no ? My worry is (1) that pseudo-randomness is not proven for BLS and (2) even if it is, is it as well for malicious key generation ?

Comment: The output of a random oracle on inputs that an adversary cannot predict (like a signature on a message) is uniformly distributed, and consequently indistinguishable from uniform random—that's the really easy part that works for any signature scheme!  _Uniqueness_, which has to be proven specifically for BLS since the standard notion of security doesn't entail uniqueness, holds for _any_ public key in $G_2$.  That is, there is no public key in $G_2$ for which uniqueness fails to hold.

Comment: If I hash the output of a *biased* dice (unpredictable by adversary), the output distribution is *not* uniform, even with hashing (I'll get some values more often than others by definition), so I don't quite understand your first statement.  I'm probably mistaken but imo it boils down to the difference between uniqueness vs pseudo-randomness which are two different things (former is a weaker version of the latter according to wikipedia). Micali shows how to use the Goldreich-Levin construction to pass from a "unique" function to a pseudo-random one (but it's very inefficient).

Comment: As long as the inputs to a random oracle are distinct, the outputs are independent uniform random bits. Assume every possible value of $\sigma$ has probability at most $1/n$ from the adversary's perspective. The adversary hopes to distinguish $H(\sigma)$ from a uniform random bit string $U$ of the same length. Unless the adversary _guesses_ $\sigma$ exactly (an event with probability below $q/n$, with $q$ queries), the two random variables $H(\sigma)$ and $U$ have the same distribution—uniform random—because every input the adversary has submitted to the $H$ oracle is distinct from $\sigma$.

Comment: "As long as the inputs to a random oracle are distinct," So you are saying it's enough for the input to be distinct, but not necessarily have enough entropy, i.e. random ? That was my worry that we could bias the input either via malicious key generation or message entropy (depending on the protocol of course).